# Display a sweet alert box when login is successful in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I tried to edit `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`
but it is not working, you can see part of my code in here:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            alert()->success('You have been login.', 'Hello!');
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I want to use uxweb sweet Alert package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach `->with` right after redirect helper.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('success', 'You have been login.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

1. `success` is the key name *(you can add anything that suits you)*
2. Second parameter is the message you want to pass.

This will pass a flash session to the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` which can only be accessible for one request *(Current request)*

Then add a if condition on your home page

```php
@if(session('success'))
  <div class="error">{{ session('success') }}<div>
@endif
```

Comment: i want to use uxweb sweet Alert